# Notification auto cancel is not working in action button click

Tags: android

I need to cancel the notification, when its action button clicking.
It is working when the user click on notification.

My code is given below.I have used this notification to open the messaging platform.

```
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() /* Request code */, chooser,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                        0, "SEND", pendingIntent
                )
                        .build();
         Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         NotificationManager notifManager = null;
        final int NOTIFY_ID = 1002;
        //There are hardcoding only for show it's just strings
        String name = "my_package_channel";
        String id = "my_package_channel_1"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
        String description = "my_package_first_channel"; // The user-visible description of the channel.
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        if (notifManager == null) {
            notifManager =
                    (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        }

            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, sendIntent, 0);
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small_icon) // required
                    .setContentText(message)  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))
                    .addAction(action)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(message)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Cancel the `Notification` when you handle the action `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have done so far.

Comment: my action is opening messaging platform

Comment: Route it through your app first. That is, have the action `PendingIntent` target a `BroadcastReceiver`, then you can cancel the `Notification` and start that messaging `Intent` from there.

Comment: it is working for me